# DNS has stopped working on my Win server 2008 box - how can I troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain

I have a single site hosted with IIS on a dedicated Windows Server 2008 box. Recently, the domain name has stopped resolving and is returned as "unreachable" by ping - the server itself is fine, and the site still accessible by IP address. What could have gone wrong, and how can I track the problem down and solve it?

Comment: The title of your question would imply that DNS is not working on a single machine (ie no web sites are resolving from one machine), but the body of your message would imply that dns is not resolving for one particular website (ie one website is not resolving from all machines). Which is it?

Comment: The machine in question is a webserver, and the site hosted there is no longer resolving anywhere. I've been looking into it, and it seems like a Plesk issue - I'm getting the error "Warning: The domain is still suspended for the following reason: Domain is expired.", even though it's registered until 2014.

Comment: It sounds like you need to contact the registrar for this domain.

Comment: The domain seems alright, it's still looking like this is a Plesk issue. The license is in it's "grace period", and it seems that Plesk automatically disabled DNS with no warning. Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is [Iptools.com](http://www.iptools.com/).  You can start troubleshooting any web-based issues from DNS to IP connectivity.  It'll help you track down registrants and so on as well.